# firestore timestamp in nodejs admin SDK

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to convert a timestamp from firestore to Date object inside NodeJS admin SDK. But i am always getting the error that toDate() is not a function.Why? How can i convert a timestamp to Date object in admin SDK.?

Here is the code what i have tried.

```
this.getService.sample()
  .then(doc => {
    const callable = this.fns.httpsCallable('myTestFn');
    const data$ = callable({ text: 'google', arraySize: 10, date: doc.data().date });
    data$.toPromise()
      .then(e1 => {
        console.log(e1);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  });
```

onCall function:

```
const original = data.text;
    const arraySize: number = data.arraySize;
    if (arraySize > 100) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'invalid request,input is above the permistted range!');
    }
    const date = data.date.toDate();
    console.log('--- This is the date---', date);
    const numberArray = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= arraySize; i++) {
        await numberArray.push(i);
    }
    const sum = await numberArray.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
    console.log('-----------sum-------------', sum)
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({ original: original,sum, createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });
    return { wish: 'A wish from function', original, writeResult: writeResult.id, numberArray, sum };
```

Answer (score 1):

Callable functions don't retain data types when passing values from the client to the server.  When you pass `date: doc.data().date` to the function, you might be passing a Timestamp type object on the client, but it's not going to show up as a Timestamp type object in the function.  It's probably showing up as a serialized version of that Timestamp, which will just be an object with two properties, seconds and nanoseconds.  If you want to treat this object as a Timestamp, you'll have to manually convert that object to one.

Comment: Yeah,it is showing an object with two properties seconds and nanoseconds.But i can create new timestamp from server side by using admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMilli(milliseconds);